Lagged Dependent Variable in Bayesian Linear Regression
I'm constructing a Bayesian General Linear model to try to model the number of customers a business has. Essentially Market Mix Modelling.
I believe the number of customers to be explained by the spend in media and some controls (fourier seasonality, trend, public holidays etc).
I basically define the model like so (leaving out some specifics because I don't believe it to be important to the question I am trying to ask):
$$y_t \sim N(\mu_t, \sigma)$$
$$\mu_t=\alpha+\beta f(X_t)+\gamma W_t$$
$$f(X_t) = \sum_{k=0}^m \lambda^k X_{t-k}$$
$$\beta \sim Exp(.)$$
$$\gamma \sim N(.)$$
$$\lambda \sim Beta(.)$$
$y_t$ represents the number of customers at time $t$, $\alpha$ is the baseline customers, $\beta$ is the vector of coefficients of the various media channels $X_t$ is our media spend data, $\gamma$ is the vector of coefficients of the various control variables, and $W_t$ is the control variable data.
$f(x)$ is an adstock function which accounts for media spend accumulating in the mind of customers and hanging around for a while before dissipating.
What I am particularly interested in is discovering the effectiveness of the media spend for different media types, so basically $\beta X$ over a period of time in the past. Forecasting is not a priority at the moment.
It makes sense to me that the number of customers at time $t$ should be influenced by the number of customers at time $t-1$. Indeed when I run the above model and look at the residuals there seems to be evidence of autocorrelation. So I feel that I should re-define $\mu_t$ as
$$\mu_t = \alpha+\beta f(X_t)+\gamma W_t +\eta y_{t-1}$$
When I do this, obviously the explanatory power of the media variables is going to be suppressed, and so media will be seen to be less effective over the period of time I am looking at.
Is this fair? The number of customers today is driven in part by the number of customers yesterday, but yesterday's customers themselves were driven in part by media. So should I be ascribing the effectiveness of the lag variable at $t$ the media variables from the period $t-1$? Or would this be double counting?
Sorry if this is a little convoluted, thank you for any opinions on this.

I think it makes sense to me. Your $\eta$ can probably also be modeled more formally as another 'marketing', called word-of-mouth, or good-previous-experience. You may want to play with the form of your autoregression to ensure correct long-term behavior. As it stands, if you turned off your media spending in the next month, but left the $\eta$ term, would the number of customers eventually drop? What are the restrictions on $\eta$ for this to be so?

I suppose I would be restricting it to be in the range (0,1), and model the $\eta$ parameter with a beta distribution. This would ensure that if I turned off all media, the number of customers would trend eventually down to some asymptote > $\alpha$.
To be clear, are you suggesting that I replace the lagged dependent variable with another quasi-marketing variable that is independent of the existing marketing variables? I agree this would stop me from estimating an artificially low media effectiveness, but would it be enough to solve the autocorrelation problem?

I think negative $\eta$ would work too. That's why I suggested to simulate it. Regarding the quasi-marketing variable. It might work. I don't think it is too dissimalr to what you have now. This is why I opened with 'it makes sense'.

I would recommend reading the following papers on this topic. (1) "To Lag or Not to Lag?: Re-Evaluating the Use of Lagged Dependent Variables in Regression Analysis" and (2) "Why Lagged Dependent Variables Can Supress the Explanatory Power of Other Independent Variables". This may seem like  a simple question, but after dealing with a similar issue for a while, I have realized it is not.

Looks highly relevant, would you mind please providing links to these?

You can google them

Hi Joe: the first one seems only available by emailing the author on researchgate which I did. But I could have missed it being available straight away.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-science-research-and-methods/article/to-lag-or-not-to-lag-reevaluating-the-use-of-lagged-dependent-variables-in-regression-analysis/F0B1870165C3FD4AB5CE69D618DF46FD Can you access from here?
